# Umbraco: Create CheckBoxList property with prevalues from mvc model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

What I want to do is create a CheckBoxList property so the editor could choose facilities specific for current page (hotel name) in BO, and render content based on what is checked.

I've created a model:

```
public class Facility
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string IconUrl { get; set; }

    public List<Facility> GetFacilities()
    {
        return new List<Facility>() 
        {  
            new Facility() { Id = 4, Description = "Free parking", IconUrl = "" },
            new Facility() { Id = 6, Description = "Spa", IconUrl = "" },
            new Facility() { Id = 7, Description = "Free Wifi", IconUrl = "" },
            new Facility() { Id = 2, Description = "Tennis", IconUrl = "" },
            new Facility() { Id = 9, Description = "Room service", IconUrl = "" },
            new Facility() { Id = 10, Description = "Fitness", IconUrl = "" }
        };
    }
```

}

How can I create a CheckBoxList with the values set in GetFacilities() method? Or should I create a new class in AppCode folder with this method? Where is the best place to put this kind of functionality, and how can I achieve this?

Comment: Is the model you pass to your view `List<Facility>` and do you want to post back the selected (checked) values?

Comment: haven't passed it yet because I don't know how to achieve the hole process yet. So I should pass this model to the view? and how can I  create the CheckBoxList property with the hardcoded values (to check them in Back-End)?

Comment: The second part of your question is opinion based but its generally accepted that view models should be dumb and only contain properties that you what to display/edit in the view. My recommendation would be to not have `GetFacilities` method in the model. Where you put it depends on the structure of of your app. I assume you view would need to display some other information about the hotel so I'll post an answer concentrating on creating the checkboxes and posting back the selected values

Answer (score 1):

Your `Facility` model should contain a boolean value to indicate if its been selected

```
public class FacilityVM
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
{

public class HotelVM
{
  public int ID{ get; set; }
  ....
  public List<FacilityVM> Facilities { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Edit(int ID)
{
  HotelVM model = new HotelVM();
  model.Facilities = // populate the list of available facilities
  // Get the hotel from repository and map properties to the view model
  return View(model);
}

public ActionResult Edit(HotelVM model)
{
  ...
  foreach(FacilityVM facility in model.Facilities)
  {
    if (facility.IsSelected)
    {
      // do something
    }
  }
  ....
}
```

View

```
@model HotelVM
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  // render properties of hotel
  ....
  for (int i = 0; i < Model.Facilities.Count; i++)
  {
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Facilities[i].ID);
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Facilities[i].Description);
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Facilities[i].IsSelected)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Facilities[i].IsSelected, Model.Facilities[i].Description)
  }
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're thinking about this the wrong way as suggested by Stephen (unless I am misunderstanding your question). You are creating a list of key/value pairs and only one will be selected in the BO and so only one will published to the front-end (regardless of the use of it).

So, in the BO you only need a dropdown list with the key/values pairs. You can create this with the "Dropdown list (publishing keys)" datatype. Also consider using the "SQL dropdown" list datatype as this would give you far more flexibility.

If you then need to convert the selected ID into a `Facility` object, do this separately using a class implementing the `IPropertyEditorValueConverter` interface. See here for more information:

http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/extending-umbraco/Property-Editors/PropertyEditorValueConverters

Comment: the content editor should select multiple options, not only one. Will look into the "SQL dropdown" datatype and get back.

Comment: you mean : http://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/sql-dropdown-list-for-v7 ?

Comment: I was thinking of the uComponents datatype but I forgot that it probably wont work in 7. There is a "multiple dropdown list (publishing keys)" in Umbraco 7 though. Personally I'd go with this until you need something more complex.