# CheckBoxList contains sql data of one column and values of another but can't access the values

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, html

I am trying to create a site where the user selects different ingredients (from my Ingredients table that contains 2 columns - ingredients and cost) by letting all the ingredients be displayed in a CheckBoxList.

With the CheckBoxList, the user can add as many of the ingredients as they want, but when they click the submit button, it should take them to the final page - and at the top of that page it should link the value (the cost of each selected ingredient) in the textbox.

So I want to show the ingredients' name then its cost, then the next ingredients' name and cost and so on.

At the bottom it should display the total cost of all the ingredients together.

But I can't seem to find any guides on how to access and display the value of my checkboxlist ( by value I mean the cost of the ingredient ). I have no idea where to start and I've been struggling on this for a while now.

If anyone has any ideas on how to do this I'd be grateful if they could please let me know.

Comment: Where have you looked? What does your current code look like? We can't suggest things until we know what you've already done.

Comment: Without seeing ant code its impossible to give you an answer, but the idea is to create a view model representing what you want to display. The `IngredientViewModel` would contain properties of `Ingredient` plus an aditional property `bool IsSelected` that is bound to the checkbox. When you post back, you get the selected ingredients by cheking the value of `IsSelected`. [This question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26403028/umbraco-create-checkboxlist-property-with-prevalues-from-mvc-model/26404162#26404162) may give you some ideas